# Widget Click not Working?

Tags: android, android-widget, click, commonsware

I am trying to implement widget based on commonsware code 'LoremWidget', see [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget) at Github

The problem is that the click is not working

on WidgetUpdate, same as [WidgetProvider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/lorem/WidgetProvider.java)

```
for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) 
{
 RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
 Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
 PendingIntent configPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
 remoteView.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.imgNext, configPendingIntent);
 appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
}
```

in the manifest, similarly as [Manifest](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.widget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
         android:name=".WidgetConfig"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
              <action
                android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="BasicWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
      <service android:name="WidgetService"
               android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

WidgetService, similar to [WidgetService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/lorem/WidgetService.java)

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService 
{
    private static final String TAG=WidgetService.class.getName();
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "inside remoteview");
        return(new WidgetFactory(this.getApplicationContext(),
                                     intent));
    }
}
```

WidgetFactory getView method as [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/lorem/LoremViewsFactory.java)

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int arg0) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "inside the getview at");
        RemoteViews row=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            row.setViewVisibility(R.id.imgNext, View.INVISIBLE);
        Intent i=new Intent();
        Bundle extras=new Bundle();
        return(row);
    }
```

Questions:

**1.** why is widget not updating, no logs are generated infact the only log relevant to my code is

05-15 23:24:27.648: I/ActivityManager(161): START {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.demo.widget/.WidgetService bnds=[509,299][547,337]} from pid -1

**2.** Is this the right way to implement just a simple click in widget, is there any other way for it, is this widgetfactory the only way?

Comment: Does the LoremWidget sample work when you use it without modifications?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, it does work, it displays list of words and displays a toast when clicked on an list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider reading [the book for these samples](http://commonsware.com/Android), specifically the chapter that covers this sample, as you would have found your answers there.

> why is widget not updating

Because you are creating an activity `PendingIntent`, with an `Intent` that points to a service, from what I see:

```
 Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
 PendingIntent configPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
 remoteView.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.imgNext, configPendingIntent);
```

This does not match [what the sample does](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/lorem/WidgetProvider.java).

> Is this the right way to implement just a simple click in widget, is there any other way for it, is this widgetfactory the only way?

This is how you process clicks in an `AdapterView` used in an app widget.

Comment: thank you, i understood the part about adapter view, correcting it.

secondly, i do not want to perform/load another activity to toast a message, i want to update the widget itself on click?? will these method suffice that and how/, please update the code for it?

Comment: @AkhilJain: You are welcome to update the app widget at any time, using `updateAppWidget()` on the `AppWidgetManager`.

Comment: the widget has some other code, already to refresh the view every 5/10 seconds , based on set timer, the view is updated(using `updateAppWidget()`), but i want it to update when click is done, i am sorry, i am new to widget development, the widget does do not do anything on updating in `getView` method

also  here you actually calling another activity to display another activity using `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, which starts another activity, which i do not want

Comment: @AkhilJain: "the widget has some other code, already to refresh the view every 5/10 seconds" -- that is not a good idea for the user's battery, RAM, and CPU. "which i do not want" -- then delete that code and replace it with something that you do want.

Comment: in that way i am atleast able to update the widget, i do not know other way to update the widget UI.

question still the same, update the widget UI

Comment: @AkhilJain: You are welcome to update the app widget at any time, using `updateAppWidget()` on the `AppWidgetManager`.